# Palindrome Checker for strings in C

Tags: c

I'm a new CS student and I was having trouble with my palindrome function. It works with single words perfectly fine and it also works with some multi-words, such as "race car", though not all. For my assignment, one of the words that I need to check is "dot i tod", though I can't get the palindrome to work properly. I would appreciate any help! (Assume only one space between words and all words are lowercase)

EDIT: I realized that I should've put the beginning of my function, so I'll put that in now.

```c
char sentence[20] = "dot i tod";
int len = strlen(sentence);
int i = 0;
int end = len;
char left[i];
char right[end];
 while (i < len){
   printf("%c ", sentence[i]);
      printf("\n");
      printf("%c ", sentence[len - i - 1]);
      printf("\n");
   if (left[i] == right[end - i  - 1]){
     i++;
     end--;
   }
   if (left[i] == ' '){
     i++;
   }
   if (right[end] == ' '){
     end--;
   }
   if (left[i] != right[end]){
     printf("Not a palindrome");
     break;
   }
   if (i >= end){
     printf("Palindrome");
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: What are `left`, `right`, and `sentence`?  It seems some code is missing.

Comment: That is, I would expect perhaps `char *left = sentence; char *right = sentence + strlen(sentence)` or similar, but then using `end` as an index to `right` rather than decrementing `right` is weird.

Comment: You might want to double check your first conditional

Comment: If you are ignoring the spaces, you may want to check them first. Also, think about how far `i` has to go to check if the string is a palindrome (`len` or `end`?).

Comment: I would assume `i` would only have to go as far as `end/2` to get halfway through the word or set of words

Comment: Note that `end` is changing at every iteration. I'm not saying that it shouldn't, just look carefully at the conditions. You added `char left[i]; char right[end];`, but those lines are declaring two *uninitialized* array with variable length.

Comment: Should I just use sentence[i] and sentence[end] instead then? Would there be a point using left and right?

Comment: Yes, you could, or declare two pointers (*if* you've already studied those) `char const *left = sentence; char const *right = sentence + len - 1;` and use theese instead.

Comment: I have studied some pointers; I understand why *left = sentence but might I ask why you decided to do *right = sentence + len - 1?

Comment: Given `char const *sentence = "abcde";` and `int len = strlen(sentence);`,  we have `len == 5`, so that `sentence + len` would be equal to `&sentence[5]`, which is a pointer to the null-terminator (`'\0'`) which ends the string. To point to the last character of the string, `'e'`, you need to subtract one (after having checked that size is at least 1, of course).

Answer (score 0):

For starters these declarations

```
char left[i];
char right[end];
```

are incorrect and do not make sense. For example you may not declare a variable length array with the size equal to 0.

But if instead of the variables `left` and `right` (that is instead of uninitialized arrays) to use the variable sentence then nevertheless the logic of your program is incorrect.

Let's assume that the string contains only one character for example `'A'`.

In this case the condition in the if statement evaluates to logical true

if (sentence[i] == sentence[end - i  - 1]){
i++;
end--;
}

As a result after the increment of `i` it will point to the terminating zero `'\0'`. While after the decrement of `end` it will point to the first and single character 'A'.

After that this if statement will evaluate also to the logical true

if (sentence[i] != sentence[end]){
printf("Not a palindrome");
break;
}

because now
And the program outputs that the string is not a palindrome.

Always try to write a more generic function.

For example the function can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_palindrome( const char *s )
{
    const char *first = s, *last = s + strlen( s );
    int success = 1;
    
    do
    {
        while ( first != last && isspace( ( unsigned char )*first ) ) ++first;
        
        while ( last != first && isspace( ( unsigned char )*--last ) );

        if ( ( success = first != last && *first == *last ) ) ++first;
    } while ( success && first != last );
    
    return first == last;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "race car";
    const char *s2 =  "dot i tod";
    const char *s3 = " 1 2 3 2 1 ";
    const char *s4 = " 1 2 33 2 1 ";
    const char *s5 = " 1 2 34 2 1 ";
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"race car" is palindrome
"dot i tod" is palindrome
" 1 2 3 2 1 " is palindrome
" 1 2 33 2 1 " is palindrome
" 1 2 34 2 1 " is not palindrome
```